# oozie-error-message: E0803: IO error, E0808: Disallowed user property [user.name]

Tags: oozie, rest-client, oozie-coordinator

In the post message, I've a property user.name and oozie responds as follows:

oozie-error-message: E0803: IO error, E0808: Disallowed user property [user.name]

When I remove the property, It gives the following error message:
oozie-error-message: E0401: Missing configuration property [user.name]

It looks crazy and not sure what it wants.
Eventually I need to pass this property in the POST request.

Comment: Anyone there to answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming the property to be username (no dot)? It could be that it really doesn't like the dot in the name.

Comment: Yes it worked!  That was the problem but the error message was not obvious. Thanks Scott!

Comment: Glad to hear it! The error messages are rarely obvious, unfortunately …